# AWS S3 how to get prefix cost in period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a bucket that receives something around 20 new prefixes in a day.

The prefixes have files that are our products, and we need to know how much each product costs to keep on air.

I was researching how to get the total cost of each product (storage and data transfer) with ['Cost Explorer'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html) and ['CloudWatch'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html).

The first does not seems to help me, while cloudwatch does have prefix or tags options, but I need to previously specify which prefix to watch over.

Is there a way to get this cost without previous configuration?

Comment: You can perhaps take pointers from this blog post: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/mystery-behind-s3-costing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cost is easy, since it is based on volume of data. Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a daily listing of content.

Access costs is not available broken down by prefix. Instead, use [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) to break down access by object and, therefore, by prefix. Then allocate the billed data transfer costs amongst prefixes. Use **Bytes Sent** to determine volume.

Comment: Sadly, we do not had AcessLogging on. But for future referencess will work. Thanks.